# using multiprocessing in windows with multithreading python

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a script which works like that, a list of element and a function,:

```
def fct(elm):
   do work
```

after that I start the threads (3) wherein the end of every thread I print the name of the element like this:

```
jobs = Queue()


def do_stuff(q):
    while not q.empty():
        value = q.get()
        fct(item=value)
        q.task_done()


for i in lines:
    jobs.put(i)

for i in range(3):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(jobs,))
    worker.start()

jobs.join()
```

what I wanna do is whenever a three is done (a file is saved) starting another process which has to read the file and apply another fct2
note: I'm using windows

Comment: So basically, after this program terminates, you want to automatically run a different program?

Comment: in parallel whenever a thread print the name i should take that result file and apply another fct and the other threads are working